# How to make characters between , and : bold in a string

Tags: javascript, material-table

I have a column in Material-Table which contains a vvery long string.  I want to format this string such that when it is rendered, text in the column will be displayed like this: ***DomainName:*** Corporate, ***DomainLeader:*** Doe, John, ***EmployeeNumber:*** 123456, .......

I have this code which is used in another column to split a string into separate lines to improve readability:

```
render: (rowData) => (
    <Box style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        {rowData.Taxonomy.split(", ").map((b) => (
            <Box style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <Box style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{b.split(":")[0]}:</Box>
                <Box>&nbsp;{b.split(":")[1]}</Box>
            </Box>
        ))}
    </Box>
),
```

Comment: Where's the question? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Why not just wrap the content you  want bold with a `<b>` tag. It will not work with custom fonts if you didn't load a bold font

Comment: I want to display Text in the column as it appears above.  I want to make Text such as DomainName: bold.  I cannot just wrap it <b> as the text is coming from a JSON response.  The response looks something like this: `"details" : "DomainName: Corporate, DomainLeader: Doe, John, EmployeeNumber: 123456,........"`  The code above splits this JSON response at the `,` and creates a new line.  It also makes the Text up to `:` bold.  I want to change it to just make the text up to `:` bold and not make a new line

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code in my question to get the desired outcome.

```
render: (rowData) => (
    <Box style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        {rowData.details.split(",").map((b) => (
            <>
                <b>{b.split(":")[0]}:</b>&nbsp;{b.split(":")[1]},&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </>
        ))}
    </Box>          
),
```